# Как закешировать все статические файлы и все представления на ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, кэширование

Нужно, что б при запуске проекта все файлы закешировались и быстрее отдавались клиенту.
Как закешировать все статические файлы / и все представления на ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Поставить перед сервером кеширующий реверсивный прокси. Сам iis вроде может им выступить.

Comment: Используй стандартный механизм html5 appchache (https://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). Генерируй его самим MVC как тебе угодно